# Graph theory - chromatic numbers

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

The vertices of the graph G are the numbers 1,2,...,64, and two vertices are adjacent if and only if one the corresponding numbers divides the other. Determine χ(G), the chromatic number of G.

I know that 64 has to be adjacent to 1,2,4,8,32 but im not sure what the end result would be.

Comment: The powers of $2$ make a 7-clique (you missed $16$ from your list) so $7$ is an obvious lower bound. There are $216$ of $2016$ possible edges. This is fairly sparse so I'd expect $7$ to be the answer, though this doesn't constitute a proof.

Answer (score 4):

Given seven colors $\{c_0, c_i, \dots, c_6\}$, we can color each integer with a prime factorization of length $i$ by the color $c_i$. (For example, $12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ would get the color $c_3$.)

You should check that this is a proper coloring of $G$, and (as suggested by @nickgard in the comments) notice that you need seven different colors to color the integers $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64\}$, so we can't do better.

This is not the only possible solution, but it's one you could have obtained greedily: if you go through the integers $1, 2, 3, \dots, 64$ in order, and give each integer the first color that doesn't appear on any of its divisors, then you obtain precisely this coloring. That's not always a good strategy to color a graph, but it's often worth a try.